# Why object becomes different after save/load to/from RData?

Tags: r, object, load, save, rdata

I have a large [ExpressionSet](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Biobase/html/class.ExpressionSet.html) object ([Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org)) named `eset`. Can you explain why this happens? Why the object's copy is not identical to the original one after save/load?

```
> e2=eset
> identical(e2,eset)
[1] TRUE
> save(e2,file="test.RData")
> rm(e2)
> e2 # just to check the removal
Error: object 'e2' not found
> load("test.RData")
> identical(e2,eset)
[1] FALSE
```

Are there other ways to check the identity of two objects?

If needed I'm working with R 2.15.1 under Windows 7.

Comment: Just a guess, maybe this datatype stores partially on disk?

Comment: Does this happen with smaller objects?

Comment: try `all.equal` instead of identical--this will tell you how the objects differ.

Comment: Perhaps there is an appended class?

Comment: @Ista: Yes, `all.equal` returns TRUE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Environments are one of a few R object types (connections are another) for which saving and loading aren't exact inverses.

```
e <- new.env()
f <- e
identical(e,f)
# [1] TRUE
save("f", file="f.Rdata")
rm(f)
load("f.Rdata")
identical(e,f)
# [1] FALSE
```

[`ExpressionSet`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Biobase/html/class.ExpressionSet.html) objects contain an `assayData` slot, of class [`AssayData`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Biobase/html/class.AssayData.html), which is described as a "container class defined as a class union of `list` and `environment`". Though I don't have **eset** installed on my computer, I'd guess that the `assayData` slots of `eset` and `e2` make reference to different environments, causing `identical(eset, e2)` to return `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes, you are possibly right. `identical(assayData(e2),assayData(eset))` returns FALSE, but `all.equal(assayData(e2),assayData(eset))` returns TRUE.

Comment: To tell for sure, you can 'drill down' into the objects by doing (e.g.) `str(e2)`, `str(e2@assayData)`, and so on, until you can find and examine the environment that's stored in there. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, assayData refer to different environments for two objects. Looks like this is the only difference. I saw in development 3.0 version identical function will have `ignore.environment` parameter. Thanks for your help!